# Clear way to check variable isset

Tags: php, laravel

Each time I am getting some information from database I am repeating the isset checking or if the variable is true. Is there any smart way to make it in a different way?

If I will not do this and the variable is empty it gives me an error so I can't really go over it.

I believe that I am doing something not necessary and it makes code longer.

```
  $variable = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `table_name`');
  $variable2 = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `table_name2`');

  if (isset($variable)){
     if ($variable == 1){
         doSomething();
     }
  }

  if ($variable2){
     if ($variable2 == 1){
         doSomething2();
     }
}
```

EDIT: I just realized that if an empty variable did not give me any errors it would be processed through all the next functions without any sense and it would make it much more complicated to find the places where the entire script was faulty.

Well, it probably means that my problem is actually an advantage haha.

Comment: First thing to check: Do you need ALL columns of the table or just a few? If you just need a few, select only those you need. Also, if you're working with laravel, why aren't you working with [models and the ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)?

Comment: I am usually getting multiple columns but I am not sure if you understand me correctly. I mean, come on we have 2017 and empty variables are giving us errors instead of automatically make them NULL or something. Maybe I am just missing some knowledge :D

Comment: `WHERE 1 = 1'` and `WHERE 2 = 2'` Is not necessary `SELECT a,b,c FROM table` will do just fine if you want all the rows

Comment: @RiggsFolly Edited my post, thanks! + DB is laravels function and i think it just secures database returned records

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you're trying to achieve here. The return of the DB statements will be an array here and so the if statements you wrote don't make sense at all (isset will return true on an empty array and the 2nd if doesn't make sense either).

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like this:

```
Route::get('/select', ['as' => 'debug.select', function () {
    // select  
    $var = DB::select('select * from users where email = 1');

    // convert to boolean
    dd(!!$var);
}]);
```

You'll see that the result is:

```
false
```

While

```
Route::get('/select', ['as' => 'debug.select', function () {
    // Select 1 user
    $var = DB::select('select * from users limit 1');

    // Convert an array to boolean / empty arrays === false on PHP
    dd(!!$var);
}]);
```

Is

```
true
```

That being said, using your code

```
$variable = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `table_name`');
$variable2 = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `table_name2`');

if (! $variable) {
    doSomethingWhenNothingWasFound();
}

if ($variable) {
    doSomethingIfFound();
}

if ($variable2) {
    doSomething2();
}
```